# Accessing paramters passed into URL from the Controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my Rake Routes looks like this:

```
report GET /management/:id/report(.:format) report#show
```

In my controller code how can I access that :id parameter?  Is it still by `.params[:id]` ?

I think I am confused because this time id is not the last thing in a URL and it is in the middle of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can acces to the params you defined in your routes like you said:

```
# The route 
# /management/:id/report(.:format)
# will generate the following params:
params[:id]
params[:format] # optional
```

Another example:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
# will produce the following params:
params[:controller]
params[:action] # (optional)
params[:id] # (optional)

match '/search/:search'
# will produce, in the SearchController (and views):
params[:search]
```

Comment: so it is working by the "name" of the params?  if I was naming it "provider_id"  I could call that in the code?  that's cool.  Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes you do understand it correctly @user1899082! You can name your params as you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is `params[:id]`. It's just a named parameter that doesn't have to be the last part of the url. If it doesn't work please provide your routes.